# Script for batch-clipping or masking rasters in R

Tags: csv, clip, modis

I need a script that can do following batch process for all files in a folder:

a) Clip or mask each raster layer (LAI product from MODIS MCD15A3) with a vector layer (vegetation types obtained from the MODIS land Use product)

b) Calculate the average for the pixels in the clipped raster

c) Divide pixel value by 10 (the MCD15A3 is LAI x 10)

d) Create timeseries with table values (date, LAI)

e) Export to CSV

f) Delete the intermediary files

I am aware that this is multiple questions in one, but i have browsed through the Q&A's here and many other places and I have been unable to find anything that will solve the task.

Comment: show us what you've got so far

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE Jakob.  Please narrow this down to one answerable question following GIS SE guidelines.  Remember, you can always ask multiple (unique) questions. You can take the tour to get up to speed on the site here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour.  Also, these guidelines may help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I can imagine doing all this with python and gdal/ogr but this is not question, it is set of tasks which should be managed by some paid experienced GIS person.

Comment: This is not a script writing service! Always glad to help out but would like to see a good faith effort first. Please show us what you have tried and when you get stuck, post a question the the forum can help you resolve.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am working on it and will post the solutoins that I have come up with later today. I am sorry for not fully adhering to the guidelines and principles and will make sure that it doesn't happen again. 
I was not looking for a finalized script - only directions as to how to go about it.